# C# add classes to a generic List and retrieve types later

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have the following classes:

```
class A {
}
class B {
}
class C {
}
```

I add them to a list:

```
List<object> ListOfClasses = new List<object>();
ListOfClasses.Add(new A());
ListOfClasses.Add(new B());
ListOfClasses.Add(new C());
processClasses(ListOfClasses);
```

Now the part I can't figure out:

```
processClasses(List<object> myClasses) {
   foreach(object obj in myClasses) {

   doSomeWork(obj.GetType(), new OtherWork<the class of obj>());

   }
    }
```

What should go as the parameterized type of *MoreWork<>*. If I were to do it one class at a time, then I'd do something like:

```
doSomeWork(typeof(A), new OtherWork<A>());
```

otherWork in this case is the ColumnAttributeTypeMapper here: 
[Dapper Custom Attribute Mapper](http://gist.github.com/kalebpederson/5460509)

Comment: You almost certainly want to avoid doing this in the first place.  Ensure that all of the classes have a common base type (or interface) with all of the functionality that you need, and use that.

Comment: I understand, but these classes don't really have much data in common, apart from the fact that they need to processed in a similar way.

Comment: The data they have in common is likely irrelevant.  It's the operations that they all need to have that matters.  Make an interface with those operations, and use that.

Comment: Can you give an example of how they are processed? This sounds like a case for an interface as @Servy mentioned.

Comment: If they have nothing in common then the example does not really make sense (to me). Maybe you can extend your example of MoreWork and OtherWork to be more concrete to illustrate the problem you are trying to solve? Either way interfaces are **probably** the way you want to go (*I say probably because I am not 100% clear what you are trying to achieve*)

Comment: I am trying to use Dapper's custom attribute type mapping, but I don't want to do it for each Model of the table I have. Classes A, B, C are essentially reflecting tables in the database.

Comment: Do you need to pass the type to the dapper engine or something? I am not seeing how that relates to generics.

Comment: Yes! and of course there are many more classes that need to be processed. otherWork<T> is basically the ColumnAttributeTypeMapper<T>  here: https://gist.github.com/kalebpederson/5460509

Comment: Why use `List<object>` at all?  Why not just use `List`?  `List<object>` pretty much defeats the purpose of generics.  Whenever I see `List<object>` that raises a red flag in my mind that there is probably a better way, like using an interface as Servy pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (*from last edit*) and of course there are many more classes that need to be processed. otherWork is basically the ColumnAttributeTypeMapper here: [gist.github.com/kalebpederson/5460509](https://gist.github.com/kalebpederson/5460509)

If that is the only constraint for you then the easiest thing would be to create a new implementation of `ColumnAttributeTypeMapper` that was not generic but took a type parameter instead.

```
public class ColumnAttributeTypeMapper : FallbackTypeMapper
{
    public ColumnAttributeTypeMapper(object instance)
        : this (instance.GetType())
    {
    }
    public ColumnAttributeTypeMapper(Type T)
        : base(new SqlMapper.ITypeMap[]
            {
                new CustomPropertyTypeMap(
                   T,
                   (type, columnName) =>
                       type.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop =>
                           prop.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                               .OfType<ColumnAttribute>()
                               .Any(attr => attr.Name == columnName)
                           )
                   ),
                new DefaultTypeMap(T)
            })
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
processClasses(List<object> myClasses)
{
  foreach(A obj in myClasses.OfType<A>()) {
    doSomeWork(A.GetType(), new OtherWork<A>());
  }
  foreach(B obj in myClasses.OfType<B>()) {
    doSomeWork(B.GetType(), new OtherWork<B>());
  }
  foreach(C obj in myClasses.OfType<C>()) {
    doSomeWork(C.GetType(), new OtherWork<C>());
  }
}
```

Comment: Now the code breaks when a `D` is added to the list, or a `Z`.

Comment: If it only ever makes sense for these exact three types to be provided, then there simply shouldn't be one list in the first place, there should be three lists, each of one of the three types.

Comment: @Servy - that is a very generous use of the word "breaks".  This codes is "designed" to not work with additional types.

Comment: Then *actually* design it to not work with any other types, as I described, rather than writing a method that indicates it will work for *any* type, but does not in fact do so.  Creating methods that proport to do things, and then fail to do those things, are in fact "broken".

Comment: @Servy I think it is easy to use this model to create an outer loop of over the types of interest.  This is meant to show how OfType<>() works (which is really his question.

Comment: That's *not* actually his question.  His *actual* question is how to perform a generic operation given a `Type`, rather than a type known at compile time.  Note that nowhere in the question does it say that the method he's asking about only ever needs to work for three types known at compile time, rather, he lists three types as examples that would need to work with it.

Comment: @Servy also I agree with your comment to use an interface instead.

Comment: @RobPeterson That doesn't actually solve the problem.  If you pass in `dynamic` to `OtherWork` then whenever it uses `T` it'll just see `object`, not `A` or `B` or `C`.

Comment: Right you are again @Servy.

Comment: @Hogan - Servy knows everything.  And he's always right.  He's like our C# Messiah. Your code wouldn't break because you never call any types that are outside of what's declared (A, B, & C).  So, since what you wrote never calls **D** or **Z**, how would it break?    This is essentially pseudo code, and Servy here get's wired all tight when you don't work out all the logic and give functioning code to the person asking the theoretical question.

Comment: @GeoffOverfield - Thanks Geoff -- I think it is possible to always be right if you redefine the question to ask about your answer -- but I agree that the leading practice is as Servy suggests.  I think if I always answered every question on SO as explaining the Best / Leading Practice I would go bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot do this is because the compiler needs to know ahead of time the types `OtherWork` with be used with so that it can generate classes for those.

You can do this at runtime though. Using [`MakeGenericMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) to compile one later. However this is likely not the correct pattern.